# Looking for a better python Google Calendar API example

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api

I am trying to write an application that can add events to a google calendar.
There is this really neat site that lets you play with the API.
http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=calendar&_v=v3&_m=events.insert

Using that site, I was able to build a calendar event using the following
stuff.   I am having difficulty translating that into python. Assuming that I've already authenticated with oauth, How do I do this with python code?  It looks I have to build a json string and somehow turn that into an http request.  I have no clue how to do that.

Can anyone provide an example of how to accomplish the same thing with the 
Python API?

Many Thanks!

```
POST
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar_id_string/events?pp=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.ANOTHERBIGSLONGTRINGHEREFfxCTiKMIR_bDui
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
"start": {
"dateTime": "2012-05-24T14:00:00-06:00"
},
"end": {
"dateTime": "2012-05-24T18:00:00-06:00"
},
"description": "My Description"
}
```

Comment: [Interesting link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#page-6) for anyone trying to use the API explorer and needing to format a datetime string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the docs for all Python samples, for instance here is one showing how to create an event: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 14):

Just a self-plug:

There is the [Google Calendar Simple API](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api) (gcsa) for Python (developed by me). It is much simpler, more Pythonic, and object-oriented. It handles credentials, JSON formatting, datetimes/timezones, recurrence, etc. for you. Here is the [Documentation](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest).

Comment: This is a really amazing piece of work that creates a much much friendlier API which allows people not already familiar with the original to quickly and concisely get things done whilst writing intelligible code. Highly recommend!

Comment: Love it! No need to understand the API. Copied an example and am now figuring out what I need from looking at objects in a debugger. Super simple!

Answer (score 1):

Came across [this article](https://karenapp.io/articles/how-to-automate-google-calendar-with-python-using-the-calendar-api/) shows with ample screenshots.

Also, [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/karenapp/google-calendar-python-api) has ample examples.